# Hidden off-topic reasons? (with images)

Tags: support, review, vote-to-close, off-topic

I've noticed that there is hidden off-topic reasons that I can't use, when flagging or closing a question. I'd like to show you this image set to demonstrate my question(in the review queue):

1. I see 2 reasons in the explanations area(too small amount of information & minimal understanding):
   [image: I see 2 reasons in the explanations part]
2. Then I click <kbd>Close</kbd>, I see this dialog:
   [image: Closing-dialog]
   Note that there is **4 closing votes** for off-topic.
3. I continue to *off-topic because...*:
   [image: Off-topic closing dialog]

I see **2 votes** for only too small amount of information. Sometimes there is comment(and votes) for reason *Other*, but in this case there is no *Other* votes.

What happended for rest of the votes?
Where can I close post with reason *minimal understanding*?
Is there any other hidden off-topic reasons?